# JQPlot - Legenda em linha

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou criando alguns gráficos utilizando o JQPlot, porém me deparei com uma situação dificil.

Gráfico de teste:
[image: Gráfico de teste]

Como podem ver a legenda esta em sequência vertical e eu gostaria de colocar ela em sequencia horizontal.

Porém, enquanto eu pesquisa (obviamente que principalmente aqui no stack) encontrei várias formas de fazer, porém, nenhuma deu resultado.

```
  var optLegend = {
    renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
    show:true, 
    placement: 'outsideGrid', 
    rendererOptions: {
      numberRows: 1,
      numberColumns: 3
    },
```

Este é o código de definição da legenda atual, mas não consegui o resultado desejado.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Poste o resto do código, html, css etc.

Comment: Obrigado Israel, realmente a falha estava em outro lugar. No caso na importação do plugin do jqplot.

Answer (score 2):

Respondendo a pergunta, encontrei após investigar o código que a minha falha não estava no JS e sim no Twig.

Na declaração do javascript do Twig estava faltando importar a jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer.min.js', conforme abaixo:

```
{% block javascript %}
  {% javascripts 
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/util/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/util/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/util/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/util/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/util/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer.min.js'
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/teste/teste.js' output='js/teste/teste.js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
  {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Após fazer a importação correta do JS, a legenda ficou no formato certo, conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]